# How do i add prices to my comboBox items in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I would like to know how I can add prices to the following:

```
private void OrderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("0");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("10");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("20");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("30");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("40");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("50");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("60");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("70");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("80");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("90");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("100");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("None");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Chocolate");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Vanilla");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Strawberry");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Paypal");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Visa Electron");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("MasterCard");
    comboBox4.Items.Add("None");
    comboBox4.Items.Add("Small");
    comboBox4.Items.Add("Medium");
    comboBox4.Items.Add("Large");
}
```

The prices for the numbers from "0 - 100" should be "£15" each?

Comment: I don't really understand what are your trying to achieve

Comment: It sounds like you want something like: 10 Vanilla @ $15 charge Visa? An order form?

Comment: I would just like to know if I can add prices to the items when they drop down. For example if i was to select "10" in the comboBox then "£15" should appear in the total...

Comment: You can create a class to model the objects. You can also use the valuemember and displaymember without creating the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combobox shows the result of the `ToString` method as the item's name. This means you can create your own object that includes a name and price, and override `ToString` to display only the name. For example:

```
public class MyItem
{
    private readonly string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    private readonly decimal price;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return this.price; }
    }

    public MyItem(string name, decimal price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And then create and add your own objects.

```
comboBox2.Items.Add(new MyItem("Chocolate", 10.00m));
comboBox2.Items.Add(new MyItem("Vanilla", 15.00m));
comboBox2.Items.Add(new MyItem("Strawberry", 8.50m));
```

Whenever you get an item from the combobox (for example the currently selected item), the `Price` property will tell you the price. For example:

```
MyItem selectedItem = (MyItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
decimal totalPrice = selectedItem.Price + 1.00m /* Shipping */;
```

Comment: Your ToString override doesn't include the price, I would do something like `return string.Format("{0} - {1}", this.name, this.price);`.But other than that this is exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: @TheGreatCO The OP comments "_If i was to select "10" in the comboBox then "£15" should appear in the total.._" so he doesn't want the price in the combo box. But I agree, if the OP wants the price in the string, he should use your solution in `ToString`.

Comment: I misunderstood what he was asking, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you can use the ComboBox.SelectedIndex value like so:

```
if (comboBox4.SelectedIndex < 100) {
    price = 15;
}
```

I **wouldn't** put that in my code though. Writing your code this way screams "maintenance hell", so look in to restructuring your code. I was going to make a suggestion along the lines of Martin's solution of using object-orientation to store the name/price, so I'd recommend giving that a go.